# Single xpath expression to get some attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument, selectnodes

I have an XML document with some nodes like

```
<node name="xxx" id="xxx">
```

Can I use a single XPath expression to get all attribute nodes whose parent has also atrtribute `@id = 7`?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only correct and complete solution, so far. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need to define which attribute to read out - one by one.

```
/node[@id=7]/@name
```

will get the `name`

```
/node[@id=7]/@id
```

will get the `id`

etc.

Comment: Actually this is quite easy to specify in a single XPath expression -- see my answer. It isn't necessary to specify a specific attribute name.

Comment: You wrote *You will need to define which attribute to read out - one by one*. This sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//@*[not(name()='id') and ../@id = 7]
```

this selects all non-id attributes  whose parent has an `id` attribute with value the number `7`. this will accept `id='7'` and `id=' 7 '`

```
//@*[not(name()='id') and ../@id = '7']
```

this selects all non-id attributes whose parent has an `id` attribute with value the string `'7'`. This will accept `id='7'` but not `id=' 7 '`

Answer (score 1):

This will select all `id` *attribute* nodes that have the value 7:

```
//*/@id[. = '7']
```

Comment: How about selecting all name attribute with id = 7?

Comment: @user496949 - That would be: `//*[id = '7']/@name`